# How to capture screen of loaded page of user using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, screenshot, capture, screen-capture

Is there a such way to capture the loaded page screen of user browser, using my node app.

For Example if user visits the profile page, and i get the screenshot of that user loaded page.

I have tried to do so but end up getting the screenshot of my own screen.

Here is my Code:

```
var http = require("http")
var fs = require("fs")
var screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');

function onRequest(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    fs.readFile('./profile.html', null, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write('File not found')
        } else{
            res.write(data)
            screenshot("screenshot.png", function(error, complete) {
    if(error)
        console.log("Screenshot failed", error);
    else
        console.log("Screenshot succeeded");
});
        }
        res.end()
    })  
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000)
```

P.S: I want it to be done from the server side only.

Answer (score 1):

Using `desktop-screenshot` you can't take screenshot of browser. [From it's docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/desktop-screenshot):

> Take a screenshot of the computer on which Node is running

You need to use some service which runs client side like [hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/) to do that. Even then, full screen screenshot won't be possible. Browsers run in sandboxes.